# Unable to pass temporary object to a move constructor

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to come to terms with rvalue in C++11, and I encounter this oddity. As I understand, calling foo myfoo(foo()) would create a temporary foo, which is then moved to myfoo.

However, Visual Studio 2015 tells me that myfoo does not exist when I try to compile. Is this a bug?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    static int n;
    int id;
public:
    foo() :id(n) { ++n; cout << "Created: " << id << endl; }
    foo(foo &o) :id(o.id) { cout << "Copy: " << id << endl; }
    foo(foo &&o) :id(o.id) { cout << "Move: " << id << endl; }
    ~foo() { cout << "Destroy: " << id << endl; }
    void bar (){cout << "I am: " << id << endl; }
};
int foo::n = 0;

int main()
{
    foo myfoo (foo());
    myfoo.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an instance of most vexing parse. C++ interprets myfoo construction as an function returning foo with foo argument.

To fix this, you need to put additional parenthesis around temporary foo()

```
foo myfoo ((foo()));
```

Or use initialization list:

```
foo myfoo { foo() };
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't think the brackets were needed. What happens when I use foo myfoo (foo()) ? Is that invalid syntax?